# Display text on same line as block level button in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bit of text I'd like to display before (to the left of) a button, while having the button take up the rest of the container. I'm using bootstrap 3 and I can't exactly figure out.

This is the markup I'm using

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5"><strong>1.</strong> <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">button text</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-7"><a href="#">My help link</a></div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to get is like the below:

`1. |---button text---|  My help link in second column`

I end up with it like this

`1.                    My help link in second column
|---button text---|`

Do I need to put the "1." in it's own col-md-1 column? Trying that it seems to take up much too much room.

**Bootply:**

http://www.bootply.com/Ghla07h9hU

Comment: Can you create a snippet or fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky scenario.  I suggest changing out the `<button>` element for a span or anchor.  the reason is that `width:auto` on a block level `<button>` doesn't fill its container like normal block level elements.  Then of course you need to apply `width:auto`.  Bootstrap tries to apply `width:100%` for `.btn-block`, but because you want it to take the "rest" of its container width, you can't specify `100%`.  Then, you need to float your number span using `.pull-left`.  Lastly, you need to make the button not overflow into the box formatting context of the span.  You can do that several ways, but for this scenario, it's best to use the `overflow:auto` trick (`hidden` will also work).  The result?  This:

http://www.bootply.com/ER76bFVCq5

```css
.btn.my-btn {
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5"><strong class="pull-left">1.</strong> <span class="btn btn-default btn-block my-btn">button text</span></div>
    <div class="col-md-7"><a href="#">My help link</a></div>
</div>
```

Whew! That's a lot of hacking to get this to work.  Can't you just place the number in its own column?

Comment: Ah, thanks. Yeah putting the number in it's own col (size 1) takes up too much space. I'd like it to be right up against the button. Was the first thing I tried :)

Comment: @Luke understandable.  Maybe another option would be to use percentage based widths within the column.  Maybe make the span be 10% wide and the button 90%?  It would start to get wonky when the container went full width, but at that point maybe you could style it differently than the desktop views.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block;` on your button.

Also, that's the right of the `button` not left.

Comment: The text I want to be on the same line as the button is the "1.", to the left. The "My help link" part is in a separate column div.

Comment: @Luke Even so, using `inline-block` means you can have stuff in the left or right of the element and you can set the `width` and `height` of the element as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the `btn-block` class of your button, so it behaves not anymore as a block element.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5"><strong>1.</strong> 
    <button class="btn btn-default " type="button">button text</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-7"><a href="#">My help link</a></div>
</div>
```

If you want to keep the block behavior, then .row and .col-md-x needs to be imbricated **and style drop the `btn-block` class**.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 row"><strong class="col-md-1">1.</strong> <button class="btn btn-default col-md-10" type="button">button text</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-7"><a href="#">My help link</a></div>
</div>
```

[bootstrap playground](http://www.bootply.com/V02xaYc0tq)

Comment: But I want the button to be a block style button, so it fills the container. I'd have a number of these buttons (1., 2., 3., etc) with different text.

Comment: @Luke then you need to use row and col-md-x as well http://www.bootply.com/V02xaYc0tq

Comment: wasn't me (though I don't think adding another grid in there doesn't seem right to me...)

Comment: @Luke maybe you should rethink styling inside here without bootstrap and add an extra class to this block, so you can style things in there as you wish :) (bootsrap is great to do bootsrap but not so flexible for something else)